# Keeping multiple .gitignore files (local and remote) in the same repository

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a repository with a .gitignore file, which excludes build paths (eg. `vendor/` from Composer).

I also have some local IDE paths (eg. `.idea` from PhpStorm) that I want to ignore, but that aren't in the repository's .gitignore file.

I'm not sure how to do this. If git looked for files like `.gitignore_*` in the folder, then I could just add a `.gitignore_local` that contains (among other things) its own name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For local ignores, you can add them to the `.git/info/exclude` file. This is not shared to remote repositories.

So add to `.gitignore` all the files that should be ignored by anyone working with the repository. Add to `.git/info/exclude` files you use personnally but other people have no reason to have them, therefore to ignore them.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a second .gitignore file with a single asterisk in the `.idea` directory. Thus all files in this directory are ignored and the directory itself is not shown as untracked file.